# Black line at bottom of elastic scrolling in uiwebview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, ios7

I have a hybrid iOS app that is essentially a uiwebview that loads HTML from our server. There's a fixed position top bar, a fixed position bottom tab bar, and a scrollable/draggable middle content section with content loaded via AJAX. However, sometimes a one-pixel, gray (#838383) line appears at the bottom of the middle content section when you scroll past the bounds of the content, ie, elastic scrolling. However, it's not consistent. In some tabs of the app, it doesn't show up at all, and I can't figure out what's causing it to appear or in some cases not appear. I've searched all the server-side CSS and HTML for "838383" but nothing turned up.

## Normal state:

[normal state http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line3.jpg](http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line3.jpg)

## Elastic scrolling shows gray line:

[scrolling with gray line http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line.jpg](http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line.jpg)

## Elastic scrolling on different page does not have gray line:

[scrolling on a different tab does not have gray line http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line2.jpg](http://msr-cf.matt.re/lio-app-line2.jpg)

Has anyone experienced this before, know why it's happening, or have a solution?

Comment: Any idea what the difference in HTML/CSS is? If nobody knows specifically, you should be able to find this yourself. I'd start by baking the HTML/CSS into the app and feeding it to the web view various. Cut off various slices of one, then the other, to see what flips the behaviour.

Answer (score 10):

This may slow down rendering a bit, but try the following:

```
webviewView.opaque = NO
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the problem... the bar still shows up.

Answer (score 4):

You have to adjust UIWebView: set opaque NO and clear background color simultaneously:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*